# Visual Studio 2017 - Change text editor font color for const variables?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I would like the text editor in VS2017 to show const variables as a different color. For example:

```
const string MY_CONSTANT = "hello";  
void doStuff()
{
    var v = MY_CONSTANT;  // I want "MY_CONSTANT" here to be a different color
}
```

**Edit:** I have looked in the "Fonts and Colors" settings and do not see an obvious option for this.

Comment: You can change colours only in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors` and as far as I know, there is no such a option. It is possible that someone made an extension to add more colours, but I do not know such a extension.

Comment: This kind of highlighting requires a parser.  But VS uses a lexer, so can't classify user-defined identifiers.  A lexer has some advantages, very fast and still works when the code syntax is complete borken.  That is why you can't find anything back in the Fonts and Color dialog, you'd need to go shopping for extension.